# Geometric distribution with general random variable

Tags: r, statistics, distribution

I got this exercise for my homework in the "Statistical Theory" course.

We were asked to find a geometric distribution for a random variable, so far this is my code and the graph immediately after it.

> Define a discreet random variable starting from the Uniform(0,1)
> distribution. Simulate for n=1000 and plot the distribution of it’s
> mean as the function of n and the PMF. Add a horizontal line for the
> theoretical mean (find it analytically, write your solution in tex,
> you may use a known for this distribution formula).
>
> Geometric(p) Choose the p parameter randomly from U(0,1) while writing
> your code for a general p. Please avoid “magic numbers” inside the
> code.The writing shoud be strictly parametric.

**My question is, how can I get a better and more accurate result? My goal is for the blue line to converge as much as possible to the original value of Expected value(Mean).**

```
library(glue)

p = runif(1) # choosing random p
n = 1000

real_avg = 1/p

cum_sum = 0
avg = numeric()
for (i in 1:n) {
  cum_sum = cum_sum + ceiling(log(U[i],10)/log(1-p,10))
  avg=c(avg,cum_sum / i)
}
plot(1 : n, avg, type = "l", lwd = 2, col = "blue", ylab = glue("Oberved Mean for p={round(p,digits=4)}"),
    xlab = "Number of Experiments")
    abline(h=real_avg,col="red")

print(glue("p={round(p,4)}"))
print(glue("E[X]={1/p}"))
```

[image]

Comment: Where does `U` come from? Are you sure the result is different from what a random walk would be expected to produce? Reversion to the mean is a tendency, not a rule.

Comment: I don't think you're really understanding the point of the assignment. You definitely shouldn't be trying to game the system and get it as close as possible. If you're simulating properly then the results are what they are - why would you think you need to get the results closer?

Comment: Cross validated has a bunch of topics on this

Comment: The logs should be natural logs, not base 10, but since you're taking them in both numerator and denominator the biasing constant gets cancelled out. You also omitted `U <- runif(n)` from what you posted. I think your biggest problem is that the p_hat is being inverted, so deviations due to its variance can asymmetrically  distort the results for sample sizes as low as 1000. Bear in mind that political polling has margins of error p+/-0.03 for a 95% CI for those sorts of sample sizes, and needs sample sizes in the ballpark of 9,000 to get down to p+/-1%.